# Why am I getting an error in first case but not in second?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I started learning OCaml recently and came across the following problem:

*Write a function `last : 'a list -> 'a option` that returns the last element of a list. *

I tried the following code:

```
# let rec last = function
| [] -> None
| _ :: t -> last t
| [x] -> Some x;;
```

I got the following response:

```
Characters 65-68:
Warning 11: this match case is unused. 
val last : 'a list -> 'a option = <fun>
```

But the following code compiles without an error:

```
# let rec last = function
| [] -> None
| [x] -> Some x
| _ :: t -> last t;;
```

giving the response

```
val last : 'a list -> 'a option = <fun>
```

So, my doubt is why just by changing the order I am getting the error?

*Any remarks and guidance will be highly appreciated.*

I asked this question on [programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/275345/165839) As per suggestion I am asking on overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in this line,

```
| _ :: t -> last t
```

what is `t`?  it's a list!.  That means it could either be a cons cell of `(a :: a list)`, or it could be `[]`.  Since this case, along with the first, now match every possible list, the third case cannot be reached.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more doubt 
"   let rec compress = function
    | a :: (b :: _ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t
    | smaller -> smaller;;"
In this code, I understood(think) that smaller->smaller is required as the case [] wont be covered other wise(compiler gave me this warning.)
But when i tried to replace it with [] -> None, I am getting an error.

Can you please explain me?

Comment: It's because there are two remaining cases: `[]` and `[x]`. This comes from the fact that your first case looks at the two first elements of the list.